# wordpress search include all keywords

Tags: wordpress, search

I have this wordpress search  filter

```
 if ($query->is_search) {
    $query->set('orderby','type title');
    $query->set('order','ASC'); 
    $query->set('posts_per_page', -1);
}
```

I want to the search to return posts with EITHER search terms. 
EG. if i search "cats dogs", i want search reults to return all posts with "cats", **and** all posts with "dogs". The post **do not** have to have both in order to show up.

Is this possible?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This can only be done with plugins. What the plugin will do is build its own search index, and thus allow you to perform much powerful query than wordpress default basics.